# How to get specific column content from a multi-column layout made by CSS3?

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I have a webpage which content(single `div` and a lot of text with formatting) is splitted into several columns(30-40) by CSS3 ( through `column-height` and `column-width`)

Is there any way to get content of a specific column (the text inside that column)? Any language, framework or algorithm are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem still remains unsolved. The best solution so far was `jQuery` + `Columnizer` plugin inside the `WebView`. Since columnizer wraps every column into the `<div/>`, the rest is simple parser work.

However, there is a geometrical(?) dependency between the size of the initial file and duration of columnizer work - beware of bottlenecks :)